# BigQuery, date partitioned tables and decorator

Tags: google-bigquery, decorator

I am familiar with using *table decorators* to query a table, for example, as it was a week ago or for data inserted over a certain date range.

Introducing date-partitioned tables revealed a pseudo column called `_PARTITIONTIME`. Using a *date decorator* syntax, you can add records to a certain partition in the table.

I was wondering if the pseudo column `_PARTITIONTIME` is also used, behind the scene, to support table decorators or something that straightforward.

If yes, can it be accessed/changed, as we do with the pseudo column of partitioned tables?

Is it called `_PARTITIONTIME` or `_INSERTIONTIME`? Of course, both didn't work. :)

Answer (score 1):

First check if indeed the table is partitioned by reading out partitions

```
 SELECT TIMESTAMP(partition_id)
  FROM [dataset.partitioned_table$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__]
```

In case not you will get error:  `Cannot read partition information from a table that is not partitioned`

then another important step: To select the value of `_PARTITIONTIME`, you must use an alias.

```
SELECT
  _PARTITIONTIME AS pt,
  field1
FROM
  mydataset.table1
```

but when you use in WHERE it's not mandatory, only when it's in select.

```
#legacySQL
SELECT
  field1
FROM
  mydataset.table1
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME > DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP('2016-04-15'), -5, "DAY")
```

you can always reference one partitioned table with the decorator: `mydataset.table$20160519`

Comment: Thank you. You described the main usage of _PARTITIONTIME in partitioned tables. I am asking about the equivalent for table decorators, which allow us to access records based on their time of insertion. Does it also revolve around a hidden/pseudo column? Is it accessible? How? Thank you

Comment: There are no implementation details documented for Table Decorators so this question cannot be answered, but it is very likely that they do not use a column that you can modify.